# Saving an image in a NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

I have problem with `rotating` and saving `JPEG` `NSImage`. I have `NSView` which is flipped

```
- (BOOL)isFlipped
{
  return YES;
}
```

Then I'm applying `NSImage` rotation with following function:

```
- (NSImage*)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
  // calculate the bounds for the rotated image
  NSRect imageBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [image size]};
  NSBezierPath* boundsPath = [NSBezierPath
                          bezierPathWithRect:imageBounds];
  NSAffineTransform* transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];

  [transform rotateByDegrees:degrees];
  [boundsPath transformUsingAffineTransform:transform];

  NSRect rotatedBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [boundsPath bounds].size};
  NSImage* rotatedImage = [[NSImage alloc]
                        initWithSize:rotatedBounds.size];

  // center the image within the rotated bounds
  imageBounds.origin.x = NSMidX(rotatedBounds) - (NSWidth
                                              (imageBounds) / 2);
  imageBounds.origin.y = NSMidY(rotatedBounds) - (NSHeight
                                              (imageBounds) / 2);

  // set up the rotation transform
  transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
  [transform translateXBy:+(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2) yBy:+
   (NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];
  [transform rotateByDegrees:degrees];
  [transform translateXBy:-(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2) yBy:-
   (NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];

  // draw the original image, rotated, into the new image
  [rotatedImage lockFocus];
  [transform set];
  [image drawInRect:imageBounds fromRect:NSZeroRect
     operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0] ;
  [rotatedImage unlockFocus];

  return  rotatedImage;
}
```

Image is now successfully rotated. Later, when I'm trying to save JPEG with following code:

```
-(void)saveDocument:(id)sender
{
  NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
  NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
  NSDictionary *imageProps = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] 
                  forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
  imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType 
                                     properties:imageProps];
  [imageData writeToFile:[_imageURL path] atomically:YES];
}
```

Result `JPEG` file is incorrectly flipped... What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot for any ideas, Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did find correct solution.

```
- (BOOL)isFlipped
{
  return NO;
}
```

Then it is important to setup NSImage (thanks to pointum !)

```
[_image lockFocusFlipped:YES];
```

From now, when I'm saving image, he is correctly rotated and flipped.

Answer (score 0):

-[NSImage lockFocusFlipped:] could help.

Comment: Unfortunately, when using [NSImage lockFocusFlipped:] is result the same.